# How to overwrite a core file for certain form when its used on multiple form?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides

Is there anyway for overwrite a core file for certain page ? what i mean is i want to customize below given core file for certain form but it will be applied everywhere wherever its use.

i.e its used on billing, shipping, registration etc. i want to customize its & remove its validation for billing section on checkout. but now validation is removed from all these forms.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\widget\name.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create name1.phtml file.
and change into the file that you want.
and change in layout file to call your custom file. for certain event only.

so that for certain event your custom phtml file will call and for all other event call default file.

Comment: but i think if file name is change in local so. i have to create a new module and mention it in xml file ?

Comment: no need to do this. it will work on certain action. not for all action